# CraftBukkit 1.8.8 - Is it possible to let the client send a message by himself?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I wanna make an anti-hack plugin, which should let the client write ".msg Test". So it would print "Test" and without a hackclient ".msg Test" (ikr, not with all hackclients but with a lot).

For this the client have to write the message by his own. It is possible to do this by sending the player a message and let the client sending this ".msg"-message when clicking on the text.

But is there a way to do this without an interaction of the player?

Comment: What you're trying to do it not possible unfortunately. You can let players send a chat message via the server by using the `player.chat(String str);` method though.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible my friend

People tend to miss out the usefulness of the method

```
myPlayer.chat();
```

The method forces the player to put something in chat, and because both chat and commands go through the same stream, you can simply change a chat message to a command by prefixing with a '/'

```
myPlayer.chat("/msg test");
```

Would force the player to run the command 'msg' with arguments 'test'.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible through bukkit-api. The closest thing to this you can do is by using *Server#dispatchCommand*, but it will only execute the command if it is registered server-side. 
https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Server.html#dispatchCommand(org.bukkit.command.CommandSender,%20java.lang.String)

However, if you feel up to using NMS (net.minecraft.server) code, then

```
CommandBlockListenerAbstract.executeCommand(ICommandListener sender, org.bukkit.command.CommandSender bSender, String command)
```

should work, as this is what I saw the implementation was for command signs in the 1.8.8 spigot-server (TileEntitySign.java line:181).

Comment: It actually is possible, as stated through another answer.

Comment: @Kerooker a little new to StackOverflow. Should I just delete my answer then, or edit what I said?

Comment: im not sure. you should ask that in meta, but i think its ok